# Remote Desktop Connection (OS X computer accessing Windows computer) very slow after copying text to clipboard

Tags: windows-xp, mac, osx-snow-leopard, remote-desktop

I'm remotely connected to my work computer today, but every time I try to copy text to the clipboard the remote computer gets very slow.

If I close and reopen the connection, the problem goes away.

If I wait a long time, the problem sometimes goes away but not always.

Windows XP, Mac Os X (10.6), RDC 1.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try a newer version of RDC? 2.1 is current, but do note that 2.1 causes a kernel panic if you connect to a machine with 8-bit colour depth. The 2.0 version doesn't appear to have this fault - I have both versions installed.

There's also CoRD on SourceForge - it seems to be in active development and is popular - I've only started using it recently, and haven't seen any major issues.

http://cord.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried CoRD but couldn't get it where I needed it quickly enough. RDC 2.1 resolved the problem and is a free download from Microsoft. **Thank you!**